# Post javascript objects array into a Form in rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with some text inputs.
But I also want to include in the form post a dynamically created table that contains some selects and inputs per row, I created a function that creates an array of objects, each row is an object:

```
detalle_array = $('#detalle tbody tr').map(function() {
        var $row = $(this);
        return {
          articulo: $row.find('input[name="articulo"]').val(),
          cantidad: $row.find('input[name="cantidad"]').val(),
          precio: $row.find('input[name="precio"]').val(),
        }
      });
```

I tried by filling this into input hidden,  but its value gets = "[object Object]" or something.

How can I include this array with their contents in the form post? I found some answers that suggest to use AJAX and converting that variable into a JSON, but I'm not sure to do that in this case. I only use Ajax for other stuff.

Comment: How do you suppose you are going to send it to the server without using Ajax?

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. I was submitting the other input fields with a submit button.